# Scrolldeck with accordion content & nav 'active' position on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion, scrollto, parallax

I'm currently working on a parallax website by using scrolldeck.js. And i've found some problems that i couldn't fix so if anyone wouldn't mind to offer some help here will be great :)

Problems:

1 - The navigation menus does not stop at the "active" state. It always 1 step behind which means the active state added to the previous navigation. And that's only happen in firefox.

2 - I've added accordion content to some slices/page/section and the height will not adjust automatically based on the content inside. Is there a way that i could make the height size as a variable so that it will adjust automatically? There are also unknown spaces between each slices/page/sections that i've found the area contain accordion content.

Please click [here](http://kurosagi.x10.mx/) for the website that i'm currently working.

Thank you for your attention :)

Comment: i think the reason why the height does not adjust automatically based on the accordion content selected is because the height of each parent container was calculated and defined when the page first loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is caused by the declaration `body{margin:0}` in your normalize.css file

The cause of the second problem is that in your file "main.js" you initialize the scrolldeck before you hide the accordion.

This means that scrolldeck calculates the height of the containing elements to include the accordion's hidden content. Just swap these two things round and all will be well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  //Scrolldeck code
  //Accordion code
  //Rest of your code
});
```

Comment: hi jack, thanks for your feedback. i've tried to swap the accordion with the scrolldeck around and that works better but the height of each section did not expand based on the contents' height and it will be hidden if expanded. :) Also, i've removed the body { margin:0; } from the normalize.css and it still doesn't fix the issue on firefox